# How to leave my dogs back home?

Tags: dogs, leashes

I love my dogs. But I am a bit inexperienced. I tend to over-humanize.

I live on the countryside. We have a small plot. The dogs roam freely on it. We are most of the time around, although they mostly need to be outside, sometimes we let them into the house for some time in a dedicated space, but hey themselves may get bored.

I am without a clue though about what to do when we leave. We sometimes need to leave for shopping and other diligences and doings. Happens around once a week or so.
We leave for the city. This may easily take 8 to 10 hours.

What's the best way of leaving them behind? We can't have them be outside - they would follow us...

So either we leash them on a 2 metres leash outside, or we leave them inside the house, unleashed, but the space is limited and confined.

What do you think is best? Or even better ideas? Thanks

Comment: What breeds/size are they?

Comment: They are small street mix breed, 12 and 10kg

Comment: If toileting is not a problem, I'd leave them in the house

Comment: How "small" is your plot? Is it possible to build a fence around it?

Comment: @HarasBrummi indeed this will possibly be my next project. The plot is a bit less than 4000m2,  of which around 1000m2 is flat, and this is the space they mostly use